# Confidence interval for difference of means for TukeyHSD vs two-sample t-test?

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test, tukey-hsd-test

I have some data with categorical predictors and I'm wondering about comparing the confidence intervals of difference in means of one pairwise comparison in my TukeyHSD analysis vs that of a two-sample t-test. Which one will have a wider confidence interval and will it always be that way for every pairwise comparison?

I just don't understand what's happening, doesn't a lower p-value mean a wider CI? And if so, then why would we be able to expect TukeyHSD to have a wider/skinnier CI if the p-value for each pairwise comparison in TukeyHSD seems to be either high or low? **TukeyHSD adjusts for the probability of making type 1 errors. Bonferroni requires a lower P-value for each individual comparison to lower the family-wise error rate which I assume Tukey does as well, so if the p-value goes down, shouldn't the CI go up?**

My CI's for the pairwise comparison $D-C$ for example were:

**TukeyHSD**: $(-16.8, -4.93)$ and

**Two-sample t-test**: $(-14.91,  -6.82)$

So the CI for the TukeyHSD was wider. Why and will it always be like this?

Comment: The phrase "higher CI" is not standard and can be interpreted in various ways.

Comment: It would help to show an example with values and calculated confidence intervals so it is clear what you are asking.

Comment: @HarveyMotulsky How about wider?

Comment: But the Tukey confidence intervals apply the 95% (or whatever) confidence level to an entire family of comparisons, not to a single comparison. So the two intervals are not really comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in your example t-test interval is not adjusted for multiplicity. The quote in bold implies that Bonferroni-adjusted t-test interval would be wider that TukeyHSD's - it's because Bonferroni's procedure is more crude. But indeed, without any adjustment at all t-test interval would be narrower than with smart adjustment by HSD. So raw t-test interval size < TukeyHSD's < Bonferroni-adjusted t-test interval.